# My HTML button doesn't work. Anything wrong?

Tags: javascript, html, css, django

I just wanna ask if there is anything wrong with my button code.. here it is:

```
<button id="stop" type="Submit" class='btn btn-primary mx-sm-2 mb-1' href="/roles/meditation/meditate-timer/stop/">Stop</button>
```

The button should have redirected us to the url, but when i serve the file from localhost (I'm using Django), nothing happened. The button is not functional. I have inspected the element and found no error. Anyone has an idea why?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: By default href attribute on a button element doesn't do anything. Use `<a>` instead.

Comment: @GuyIncognito ah thank you! i didnt realize it. works perfectly now ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buttons do not support the `href` attribute. You can use an `<a>` tag (styled as a button) instead:

```
<a id="stop" type="Submit" class='btn btn-primary mx-sm-2 mb-1' href="/roles/meditation/meditate-timer/stop/">Stop</a>
```

CSS:

```css
a {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```